# Using Auto-Layout after loading NIB in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, constants, nib

I have NibVC and NibView, I set its Auto-Layout for different devices

I load NibView to NibVC with code

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    self.profileHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    self.profileHeaderView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.profileHeaderView];
 }
    return self;    
 }
```

Also I have some placeholderView, that appears in my NibVC until I do not load this code.

But then I load this View, it did not resized to constraints. Yes, It's OK because contains are did not set at life cycle of initWithCoder.

But How can I load it with constraints?

I can set frame manually, but I not like it.

```
CGFloat scale = rect.size.width / rect.size.height;
CGFloat screenW = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat scaledH = 1/scale * screenW;
rect.size.width = screenW;
rect.size.height = scaledH;
```

Also I tried this article http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/282

But I it not works for me and i did no know why, of some one could see this few lines o my code I will be very happy, there it is
http://dropbox.com/sh/0mwsn3ik8y62nlq/AAB5sE72LzefY-trmXWQ1dZYa?dl=0